# UIImagePickerView gives portion of image blank while selecting image in editing mode

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerView` to allow user to select profile image. After selecting image from `UIImagePickerView` user select portion of image (Square selection box which comes in `editing mode`) when user choose that image I am uploading it to a server and also storing it to a local machine part of the image comes as a black when I open that image on server as well as on device.

This is how image looks after uploading.[image]

Following code I am using.

```
 func launchImagePicker(){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        imagePicker.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(named:"navigationColor")
        imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: {
            self.closeSharedWindow()
        })
    }
```

following will get call when we cancel picker

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Here we are getting image from picker and uploading it.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
        if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
        }
        else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
        }
        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker{
            profileImageView.image = selectedImage

            self.uploadImageToServer(image: selectedImage , userId: (self.user?.userId)!) {

                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

following function will upload image to server

```
 func uploadImageToServer(image: UIImage,userId: String,completion: @escaping () -> ()){
        //,completion: @escaping ([String:Any])->Void
        let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)!

        let parameters = ["userId": userId]

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "profileImage",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        },
                         to:APPURL.updateProfileImage)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    self.storeProfileImageDetail(image: image)

                    guard let profileImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.9) else {
                        print("Error in JPG Representation Image")
                        return
                    }
                    //save image on local
                    self.saveImageToDisk(image: profileImage)
                    completion()
                }

            case .failure(_):
                self.view.makeToast("Failed to upload profile image.")
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
```

I am unable to understand what could be wrong any one have idea about this?

Comment: I have observed multiple images and it looks like image is shifted to the left.

Comment: what I am selecting and what I am getting have a huge diffrence in `UIImagePicker`